# Cannot comment on Redshift view's columns

Tags: database, amazon-redshift

Hello all you Redshift wizards,
I have this issue that's causing me head aches!

I create a view in Redshift:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW my_schema.my_view AS
SELECT aggr.unit,
       aggr.date_key,
       myorg.ultimate_org_sk,
       aggr.user_role      AS derived_user_role,
       SUM(aggr.users)     AS total_users
FROM my_schema.master_table aggr
INNER JOIN my_schema.my_organization myorg
        ON aggr.my_organization_sk = myorg.my_organization_sk
WHERE aggr.unit = 'weekly'
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4;
WITH NO SCHEMA BINDING;
```

This works fine.
Now When I try to comment on the view, it works ok:

```sql
COMMENT ON VIEW my_schema.my_view IS 'View of Weekly Aggregates';
```

But when I try to comment on any column:

```sql
COMMENT ON COLUMN my_schema.my_view.unit IS 'The period of aggregation (daily/weekly/monthly/quarterly/biyearly/yearly)';
```

I get an error message:
`[42703][500310] [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: column "unit" of relation "my_view" does not exist;`

Which is very strange! When I run a select, I get data back:

```sql
SELECT * FROM my_schema.my_view LIMIT 10;

SELECT unit FROM my_schema.my_view LIMIT 10;
```

Now, the really weird bit:
If I check the `information_schema` table, I find no records of my view:

```sql
SELECT table_name,
       ordinal_position AS position,
       column_name
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = 'my_schema'
  AND table_name = 'my_view'
ORDER BY table_name, ordinal_position;
```

No data returned....

But When I query the `svv_columns` table, I get back all the columns:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM svv_columns
WHERE table_schema = 'my_schema'
  AND table_name = 'my_view'
ORDER BY table_name, ordinal_position ;
```

| table_catalog | table_schema | table_name | column_name | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| my_db | my_schema | my_view | unit | ... |
| my_db | my_schema | my_view | date_key | ... |
| my_db | my_schema | my_view | ultimate_org_sk | ... |
| my_db | my_schema | my_view | derived_user_role | ... |
| my_db | my_schema | my_view | total_users | ... |

What is happening here? and how can I comment on Columns in this view?
And yes, I dropped the View and re-created it several times, but still facing the same issue!

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I also came across this issue. But I have some views that I **can** comment. I realised that if you have
`WITH NO SCHEMA BINDING;`
then you **cannot** add comments to the view!

I don't understand why this behaviour exists. I would think that the comments are on the view object, irrespective of whether it is bound to a schema or not.

Then, looking at the OP, it seems that if it is `WITH NO SCHEMA BINDING;` it probably isn't storing the info in *information_schema* table.